# Copying a folder including its contents into another folder in a Batch

Tags: batch-file, copy, directory

I'm trying to copy several folders from different directory into another using Batch.

The output path is always the same, while the Input paths are read from a file beforehand. Is there a way to copy only a single Folder from on Directory to another, not just ist Contents or the subfolder structure?

I know it is possible with xcopy and exclude, but the input directorys are in a directory with 50+ Folders that is changed dynamically, so this is not really an Option.

what i essentially want to do is:
Input: /Folder 1/Content.txt

Output: /Output/Folder 1/Content.txt

Maybe i missed out on something, help would be greatly appreciated

My code is already working, but its more of a Workaround, as i have to handle the paths given by hand.

```
for /f "skip=13" %%G in (project.properties) do (
set checktarget= %%G
set checktarget2=!checktarget:target=x!
if "!checktarget!" == "!checktarget2!" ( 
    for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%a in ("%%G") do (
        set checks= %%b
        set checks2=!checks:/=x!
        if "!checks!" == "!checks2!" (
            for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=\" %%f in ("%%b") do (
            md %LOC_TEMPFOLDER%\%%h
            xcopy %%b %LOC_TEMPFOLDER%\%%h /e /s /z
            )
        ) else (
            for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=/" %%f in ("%%b") do (
                md %LOC_TEMPFOLDER%\%%g
                xcopy %%b %LOC_TEMPFOLDER%\%%g /e /s /z
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Usually it's possible but your question doesn't provide specifics: existing .bat script and criteria to select the folder you need to copy.

Comment: You say you want to copy a folder and all of its contents, but then your example shows you copying a single file. What do you want?

Comment: the point is that i want to copy the folder and its contents instead of just copying its contents - im going to add code give me a second

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to create a new folder with the same name as the source folder and then just copy the contents normally?

Comment: thats what im doing right now, i just wondered if there is a better/less hardcoded way to do it.

Comment: What is the problem still eludes me. So far it seems your solution would be `xcopy %%b\YourSingleFolder ........`.

Comment: The problem is that %%b is the folder to be copied.